# Is it bad practice to attach an arrow function to another arrow function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Assume there is no need for `this` in any of these function. This works

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y
add.foo = () => 4
console.log(add(1, 1))
console.log(add.foo())
```

and I think its very useful for packaging up api request handlers and function calls, for example (assuming express.js):

```
const getPost = async (postId) => db.get(postId) // assuming db.get will get the post

getPost.handler = async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { postId } = req.body
    res.send(await getPost({ postId }))
  } catch (err) {
    next(err)
  }
}
```

I can then use `app.post('/get-post', getPost.handler)` and still have a nicely testable `getPost` function.

This appears good to me, I'm just wondering is this accepted practice, or is there something I'm not thinking of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const add = (x, y) => x + y
```

In the code above, `add` is an object whose prototype is Function.prototype. Just like any object in JavaScript, it can have properties. These properties can themselves be objects, of any kind. Including objects whose prototype will be Function.prototype.

It's not a bad practice. The native language actually uses this. Because your object of prototype Function.prototype natively exposes functions like Function.prototype.call or Function.prototype.apply

For instance :

```js
const add = (x, y) => x + y
console.log(add.call(undefined, 3, 4));
```

Answer (score 1):

Functions are objects and objects got methods. Thats common practice in JS, actually all static properties of classes are part of the constructor function:

```
 new Promise()
 Promise.resolve()
```

Or take jquery:

```
 $("div")
 $.ajax(/*...*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to avoid this kind of implementation, cause it can lead to a problem in the future, in case the TC39 Committee decides to add a new property with the same name of some property you already used.

Probably won't happen with `handler` (but it could), but if you start doing this in your code, it will be tempting to start extending these properties more and more.

There was a recent case related to this problem that got a lot of attention. You can read more about this here: https://dev.to/kayis/smooshing-javascript--5dpc